# List of recently installed apt packages

Tags: ubuntu, debian, apt-get, aptitude, apt

I just spent an hour trying to solve dependencies to build `freeCAD` from their slightly outdated [Wiki](http://www.freecadweb.org/wiki/index.php?title=CompileOnUnix).

Is there a way to get the packages I installed in the last hour or day with `apt-get` or `aptitude`?

My first try was `ls -t /var/apt/cache/archive` but that list packages with weird dates. for example, one I'm sure Installed just now, `python2.7-dev`, is listed as "Mar 17  2014". The only thing listed as today are a few security updates I did this morning. And there are dirs there marked from 2006. I didn't even have that install that long ago.

I can't use command line history either because I used a mix of apt-get install and aptitude. also I had several terminals and history got screwy after a while.

edit:

@jmonrio pointed to an excellent answer, but that gives me a ton of packages when i only installed a handful. it does not differentiate from what i asked to be installed from what was installed as part of the dependency chain.

Do I have any hope of getting the minimum install line for that history? i.e. without the automatically included ones.

Comment: The same question is resolved in AskUbuntu: http://askubuntu.com/questions/21657/show-apt-get-installed-packages-history-via-commandline

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17012/is-it-possible-to-get-a-list-of-most-recently-installed-packages):

Command to list recently installed packages that were installed via any method (apt-get, Software Center et al.):

```
grep " install " /var/log/dpkg.log
```

You could run this command to list only the recently installed package names,

```
awk '$3~/^install$/ {print $4;}' /var/log/dpkg.log
```

Comment: this still shows all the installed dependencies, but i think this is the best that we can get.

Answer (score 1):

If you use sudo to start apt or aptitude, all commands are written to `/var/log/auth.log`. So a `grep apt /var/log/auth.log` should give you the commands. In my case (Debian), `grep '/usr/bin/apt' auth.log* | awk '{print $15}'` returned all apt/aptitude commands neatly. Adjust accordingly. Good luck!

Comment: but as i said, history alone is not enough because some packages where selected in the graphic mode of `apitude`